# Android Custom Font with fontFamily tag instead Caligraphy Library

Tags: android, fonts

Does anybody have any idea why people tend to use caligraphy library for custom font even we can change the whole application font with just one line? Why do we need to add the hefty library to just apply custom font? I read the whole documentation of the caligraphy library but didn’t find anything which we can’t do with native android utilities.

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/allura</item>
```

Comment: Can you accept the answer or explain what you did expect from it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Calligraphy](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy) is around the Android ecosystem since 2014, most of the font features described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml) where not present at that time and when they first came out they were min-api 26 until support library closed the gap. Calligraphy had a long period where it was a reliable choice to use custom fonts.

Nowadays most (if not all) the functionalities provided by Calligraphy have been absorbed my framework alternatives, that's why the development on GitHub stopped.